# 'make' commands don't work in WebStorm Makfile Language Plugin

Tags: windows, npm, makefile, webstorm

I've faced an issue which I don't understand how to solve.
I use WebStorm on Windows. There I've installed Makefile Language plugin to launch commands automatically

```
install:
    npm ci
brain-games:
    node bin/brain-games.js
publish:
    npm publish --dry-run
lint:
    npx eslint
```

but I cannot do that, it returns error

```
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\make.exe -f *way-to-the-project*/Makefile publish

process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, npm publish --dry-run, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [*way-to-the-project*/Makefile:6: publish] Error 2
```

I've tried to run 'make' commands using Powershell and Ubuntu from Microsoft Store and it has worked well, I just cannot understand what is the problem with the plugin and how to use it properly.

Please help me with any advice :)

Comment: This error means that it can't find the program `npm`.  Either it's not installed or it's not on your PATH.

Comment: @MadScientist I've checked it and in PATH there're set this ```C:\Program Files\nodejs\``` and ```C:\Users\*my-username*\AppData\Roaming\npm```. I've added additionally this ```C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin``` but it didn't help. I reinstalled Node.js and check 'Add to PATH' for Node.js and npm but it didn't help as well

Comment: If you run `npm` from your shell prompt before you invoke make, does it work?  By "shell prompt" i don't necessarily mean your cmd.exe prompt as you show here.  I mean the shell make invokes.  If you're not sure what that is, add `$(info shell is $(SHELL))` into your makefile and see what it prints.

Comment: @MadScientist I put the command you had suggested and it returns `shell is sh.exe` but it doesn't give me any sense :D I don't understand how I can prerun _sh.exe_ before executing _make_ commands.

I tried in _Makefile Language_ plugin to add _Before launch_ and put there _sh.exe_ but it just runs and no _make_ commands are executed

Comment: @MadScientist And yeap, `npm` runs from _sh.exe_ as well when I'm in my project folder :)

Comment: I didn't suggest you should run `sh.exe`.  That is the shell that make is running.  I don't know anything about WebStorm (or even Windows, really) but if it works from the shell then all I can suggest is that the PATH that WebStorm is invoking make with is different than the PATH that you use normally, and doesn't contain npm.  You can add `$(info path is $(PATH))` to your makefile and try running it by hand, and see what the different paths are between your shell and whatever WebStorm is doing.

Comment: @MadScientist for some reasons `$(info path is $(PATH))` returns `null;*path-to-my-project*\node_modules\.bin`. That's the key reason :D Just I have no sense why here's `null` and why this path is so weird

Comment: You'll have to figure out why WebStorm is not providing the proper path.  Seems like a WebStorm issue.

Comment: @MadScientist I've found out! Just `node_modules/.bin` was automaticaly added from the project root to `%PATH%` because of the settings in WebStorm. So I just went File -> Settings -> Tools -> Terminal and unchecked this option :D Thank you for the vector of thinking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the issue like this one when you use WebStorm on Windows and try to run Makefile, make sure that in IDE you don't have checked option `Add 'node_modules/.bin' from the project root to %PATH%` in *File -> Settings -> Tools -> Terminal*.

Maybe it will save hours for you :)